# Manipulating multi-dimension array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a multi-dimension array that I have initialized using this code:

```rb
arr = Array.new(3, Array.new(3, "x"))
puts arr.inspect

# Console O/P
# [["x", "x", "x"], ["x", "x", "x"], ["x", "x", "x"]]
```

When I manipulate the above array, I get an unexpected response.

```rb
arr[0][0] = "y"
puts arr.inspect

# Console O/P
# [["y", "x", "x"], ["y", "x", "x"], ["y", "x", "x"]]
```

I cannot understand why multiple entries in the array are getting updated when I have given the exact dimension for the update.

I am referring to the [Array#initialize doc](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Array:initialize).

Contrary to the above implementation, when I try to initialize the array this way and then manipulate it, I get the expected response.

```rb
arr = Array.new(3) { Array.new(3) { "x" } }
arr[0][1] = "y"

puts arr.inspect

# Console O/P
# [["x", "y", "x"], ["x", "x", "x"], ["x", "x", "x"]]
```

Again here, I am not sure why is the implementation different from the above initialization.

Based on my understanding, the difference between the two initializations as mentioned in the above doc is:

```rb
#new(size, default_value) ⇒ Object
#new(size) {|index| ... } ⇒ Object
```

I'd expect both arrays to behave in the same fashion.

Comment: From the docs: _"With no block [...] each element is that same `default_value`"_, i.e. all 3 inner array refer to the very same array instance. There's also a dedicated section on [Creating Arrays](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Array#label-Creating+Arrays) which explains that you need the block form when dealing with mutable objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the first version re-uses the exact same array for each “line”. And therefore, changing one of the values in that array changes the array in all lines, because it is the same array.

```
arr = Array.new(3, Array.new(3, "x"))
arr.map(&:object_id)
#=> [31740, 31740, 31740] # All arrays are the same object
```

But the second version creates a new array for each line, and therefore changing one entry doesn't change the entries in the other arrays.

```
arr = Array.new(3) { Array.new(3) { "x" } }
arr.map(&:object_id)
#=> [81520, 81540, 81560] # Each array is a different instance
```